# SQL Group by & Max

Tags: sql, group-by, max

I have a following data in a table:

```
id  name    alarmId  alarmUnit  alarmLevel

1   test    voltage  psu        warning
2   test    voltage  psu        ceasing
3   test    voltage  psu        warning
4   test    temp     rcc        warning
5   test    temp     rcc        ceasing
```

I'd like to show only the most recent information about every colums group (alarmId,alarmUnit), so the result should look like this:

```
3   test    voltage  psu        warning
5   test    temp     rcc        ceasing
```

I've tried so far:

`SELECT MAX(id) as id,name,alarmId,alarmUnit,alarmLevel  GROUP BY alarmId,alarmUnit;`

Selected IDs seem to be fine but selected rows aren't corresponding to them. Could you help me?

Answer (score 29):

In `Oracle`, `SQL Server 2005+` and `PostgreSQL 8.4`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY alarmId, alarmUnit ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

In `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  mi.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  alarmId, alarmUnit, MAX(id) AS mid
        FROM    mytable
        GROUP BY
                alarmId, alarmUnit
        ) mo
JOIN    mytable mi
ON      mi.id = mo.mid
```

In `PostgreSQL 8.3` and below:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ON (alarmId, alarmUnit) *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        alarmId, alarmUnit, id DESC
```

Answer (score 19):

If you want to get the row of the max, you'll probably need a sub-query.  Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id) FROM YourTable GROUP BY alarmId, alarmUnit
    )
```

Comment: This is good standard SQL that will (or at least should) work accross a large range of platforms. If you need more performance, benchmark against the options provided by Quassnoi

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN
  (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table GROUP BY alarmId, alarmUnit)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try something like the following:

```
SELECT id,name,alarmId,alarmUnit,alarmLevel
FROM table
WHERE id IN (SELECT Max(id) FROM table GROUP BY alarmId, alarmUnit)
```

You may have to include alarmId and alarmUnit in the sub query select.

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, name, alarmID, alarmUnit, alarmLevel
from (select max(id) as id
from table
group by alarmID, alarmUnit) maxID
inner join table
on table.id = maxID.id
```