# SQL query to compare rows of table comparing a column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have imported a large CSV file into a table. A sample of the table looks like this

```
name,      eye,point,field,date,seconds,sensitivity*10,slope,intercept,T*1000

NESSA SONIA ,R,6,4,08-04-09,32658845,160,1.062300e+001,62538,  1282
NESSA SONIA ,R,6,5,20-05-09,36288632,20, 5.360101e+000,64036,   771
NESSA SONIA ,R,6,6,02-12-09,53223062,60, 3.425260e+000,64590,   767
NESSA SONIA ,L,6,4,08-04-09,32658922,230,4.629489e+000,64382,   582
NESSA SONIA ,L,6,5,20-05-09,36288515,170,2.805373e+000,64901,   511
NESSA SONIA ,L,6,6,02-12-09,53223059,220,3.528252e+000,64694,  1022
```

I have to compare Right eye and left eye "sensitivity*10" values, with matching point and field values and extract the highest(I mean the rows).

For example I have to compare first row and fourth as the point, field and date are same and extract the fourth as sensitivity is highest. I have a huge file and need to extract all values. Can Anyone help with the sql query, will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have separated the left and right eyes into two tables table l and table r and then got values which are not null using  (select  `table l`.*  from `table l`
where `table l`. `sensitivity*10` > 10)
union
(select  `table r`.* from `table r`
where `table r`. `sensitivity*10` > 10)   but after this if I compare and extract the fields using join, its giving me cartesian product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(select  `table l`.*  from `table l`, `table r` 
where `table l`. `sensitivity*10` > 10 and `table l`.`sensitivity*10`>`table r`.`sensitivity*10`) 

union 

(select  `table r`.* from `table r`, `table l` 
where `table r`. `sensitivity*10` > 10 and `table r`.`sensitivity*10`>`table l`.`sensitivity*10`)
```

Comment: I separated into two tables left and right and used this query.. figured it out.. Thanks tim peterson. and bluefeet

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SQL `MAX()` function and `GROUP BY` name.

try something like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  point, field, MAX(sensitivty*10) AS max
    FROM    table
    GROUP BY
            name
    ) tbl
JOIN    table
ON      table.point = tbl.field
```

Also, look at this other Stackoverflow Q&A which has a query similiar to the one you are interested in: [SQL Group by & Max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299556/sql-group-by-max)

Comment: Sorry, it didnt work, it gave me the single row which has point and field same. But I need to compare the left and right eye(sensitivity vales ) where point field and date are same. observe 1st and 4th row in the image

Comment: still the query is displaying the row which has same point and field, but its not comparing with other rows

Comment: yeah, the `MAX()` is getting the overall `max`. That's why there is only one row returned. I'm still trying to only figure out how to get the `max` for each person. Pretty sure the `MAX(sensitivty*10)` needs to be moved somewhere else maybe in a subquery. I'm trying but not the best at SQL, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

```
select if(t1.sensitivity*10 > t2.sensitivity*10,t1.sensitivity*10,t2.sensitivity*10) as col1  
from table t1 
inner join table t2 
    on  t1.field = t2.field 
    and t1.point = t2.point 
    and t1.date = t2.date 
where t1.eye ='R' and t2.eye ='L'
```

Comment: @bluefeet I guess the query is not quite correct, i'm not seeing in your query where `field=point`. Can you advise? thanks

Comment: how about get rid of the `WHERE` clause if R and L eyes are in their own tables?

Comment: @timpeterson he is right.. field and point of single row need not be same..  they should match of coresponding left or right eye

Comment: how about if you get rid of the `WHERE` clause?