# sql Group by and max() doesn't get the right results

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max

I have the following table

```
mes_id | user_a | user_b | message | room | time
------------------------------------------------------   
1      | 23     | 24     | hello   | 1    | 5676766767
```

`user_a` sent a `message` for `user_b` in `room` `1`

I want to get the all the last messages received for a specific user (for example user_b) per room, I have tried few queries but I didn't get the right one.

This solution didn't work for me: [sql_group_by_max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299556/sql-group-by-max)

An update

I am using 5.5.18 MySQL Server

ok

this gave me the result thanks

```
SELECT * 
FROM messeges C
JOIN (
       SELECT room, user_a, MAX( messeges.date ) AS max_time
       FROM messeges
       GROUP BY room, user_a
      )a 
ON a.room = c.room

AND a.user_a = c.user_a
AND a.max_time = c.date

WHERE c.user_b =  '396'
```

Comment: Can you add that few queries?

Comment: please add the queries that you tried. It's easier for us to spot where it goes wrong.

Comment: What database system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select * from chat C join 
(select  room,user_b,MAX([time]) as max_time
from chat
group by room,user_b)a
on a.room=c.room
and a.user_b=c.user_b
and a.max_time=c.[time]
```

If you want multiple rows, (In sql server)

```
with cte as (select *,ROW_NUMBER () 
     over (partition by room,user_b order by [time] desc) as rownum from chat)
select * from cte order by rownum
```

Comment: hi joe thank you very much i tried that and it didn't work i am using  mysql db and the table name is messeges    SELECT * 
FROM messeges C
JOIN (

SELECT room, user_b, MAX( messeges.date ) AS max_time
FROM messeges
GROUP BY room, user_b
)a ON a.room = c.room
AND a.user_b = c.user_b
AND a.max_time = c.date
WHERE c.user_b =  '396'

Comment: @Crimeira: It should work, do you have user_b = '396' in your table?

Comment: yes i want the result for a specific user,its like facebook private messages only with rooms so the logged user can view only the last messages from each user .I also tried the second answer but it didnt work some i get syntax error my table name is messages and the time field is date. thanks a lot joe

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   Select *
FROM chat a
INNER JOIN ( Select  user_a, user_b , room ,MAX(time) as max_time
    FROM chat
    group by user_a, user_b , room) b on a.user_a=b.user_a and a.user_b=b.user_b and a.room=b.room
```

Comment: thank you very much irani i tried SELECT * 
FROM messeges a
INNER JOIN (

SELECT user_a, user_b, room, MAX( DATE ) AS max_time
FROM messeges
GROUP BY user_a, user_b, room
)b ON a.user_a = b.user_a
AND a.user_b = b.user_b
AND a.room = b.room
WHERE b.user_b =  '396' and i get duplicate rows for each user not unique room,user_a and the last message (i also tried where a.user_b)