# Get user with highest number of records

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa

I have a table "Records" in my database and a column "username" where I have stored the name of the user that has the record. I want to get the user with the highest number of records. The only idea that I have is to build a method to get the number of records for each user and then to find the greatest number among them. 
Is there any SQL query to do this or a simpler method? 
Thank you.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: This is Group by and MAX problem.
[This may help][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299556/sql-group-by-max/%22This%20may%20help%22

Comment: I explained above my idea, but it is not good even for a small amount of records

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select username, count(*)
from Records
group by username
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

Comment: And to get the user with the highest number of records?

Comment: The only thing you should understand - there can be more than 1 records like that. And the query doesn't promise to return the same result all of the time.

Answer (score 2):

```
select username, count(*) As no_of_records
from Records
group by username
order by no_of_records desc
```

The above query will give all the rows with descending order of no. of records for users and for any number of limits you can use `LIMIT` keyword followed by a number

for. eg for highest `LIMIT 1`

for top 2 `LIMIT 2`
etc.

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
select username
from records
having count(*) = 
    (SELECT max(count(*)) FROM records group by username)
group by username
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  SELECT username, sum(record) total_record
  FROM Records
  GROUP BY username
  ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

EDIT :

[**DEMO SQLFIDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bed7/4)

** if you want get just the first highest , do LIMIT 1

```
 select username, sum(record) total_record
 from Records
 group by username
 order by count(*) desc
 limit 1
```

[**demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bed7/5)