# How to get the MAX result even if the MAX is different

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a code where I am pulling language knowledge and each employee has a plan year, they do not all complete them each year and in order to get their most recent one I use the MAX for plan year. Now one of the criteria is whether or not they are willing to move over seas, the issue arises that it will bring up their most recent YES and most recent NO and I just need their most recent plan year whether it be yes or no, I am having difficulty troubleshooting this. The code is as follows:

```
SELECT Employee_ID, Accept_International_Assignment, MAX(Plan_Year) AS Expr1
FROM  dbo.v_sc08_CD_Employee_Availabilities
GROUP BY Employee_ID, Accept_International_Assignment
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I shortened it to the portion that I am having trouble with, I accidentally put the whole thing up at first.

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.Employee_ID, a.Accept_International_Assignment, a.Plan_Year
FROM  dbo.v_sc08_CD_Employee_Availabilities a
INNER JOIN (SELECT Employee_ID, MAX(Plan_Year) maxPlanYear
            from dbo.v_sc08_CD_Employee_Availabilities
            GROUP BY Employee_ID) m
   ON a.Plan_Year = m.maxPlanYear AND a.Employee_ID = m.Employee_ID
```

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this will be more efficient than the accepted answer, at scale...

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT Employee_ID, Accept_International_Assignment, Plan_Year,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_ID ORDER BY Plan_Year DESC)
  FROM dbo.v_sc08_CD_Employee_Availabilities -- who comes up with these names?
)
SELECT Employee_ID, Accept_International_Assignment, Plan_Year
  FROM x WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want only the most recent decision and year as Raphael posted or if you want the yes's and the no's but always with the Max plan year for that employee.

Here is a query for the yes's and no's but Max plan year is always the max for the employee.

```
select main.Employee_ID, Accept_International_Assignment, Expr1
from (
    SELECT Employee_ID, Accept_International_Assignment
    FROM  @v_sc08_CD_Employee_Availabilities
    GROUP BY Employee_ID, Accept_International_Assignment  
) main
inner join
(
 select Employee_ID, MAX(Plan_Year) as Expr1
 from @v_sc08_CD_Employee_Availabilities
 group by Employee_ID) empPlanYear
on main.Employee_ID = empPlanYear.Employee_ID
```

Answer (score -2):

You need a subquery on the max() and join against that.

[SQL Group by & Max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299556/sql-group-by-max)