# Selecting highest value for a group

Tags: mysql

I have a select query for a mysql database which lists a series of values for a number of items:

```
Bottle of single malt scotch,   Â£15
Bottle of single malt scotch,   Â£1.00
Box of Deans shortbread,    Â£2
Box of Deans shortbread,    Â£1.00
Days fishing,   Â£10
Days fishing,   Â£1.00
Fishing reel,   Â£5
Fishing reel,   Â£1.00
```

The query is:

```
SELECT field7,field11 FROM 2007mod_mpform_results_249 ORDER BY field7,field11 DESC
```

I would like to only display the highest value for each item. Is this a simple task or do I need to get into sub-queries? I have looked for a solution but am pretty baffled by results as I am new to SQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Group by & Max](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299556/sql-group-by-max)

Comment: You don't really store '£', do you?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to select names and highest price for it, so you can try somethink like this:

```
SELECT name, max(price) as price FROM products GROUP BY name ORDER BY name ASC
```

here you're selecting names and grouping results with `GROUP BY`. `max(price)` takes highest values from that subgroup.