# An example of how to grab the last Row_number() in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, max, min

My table example:

[image]

I know that if I wanted to grab the highest score from each company I would say:

```
 where columnName = 1
```

but how do I grab the one at the end without putting columnName = 4 because I want the highest and least and each company will a different amount of scores.

Comment: Why have you tagged this MySQL when you are using SQL Server? And what version of  SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the highest and lowest scores, here's one option:

```
with cte as (
  select row_number() over (partition by company order by score) minscore,
         row_number() over (partition by company order by score desc) maxscore,
         company, score
  from yourtable
  )
select company, score
from cte 
where minscore = 1 or maxscore = 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7b185/1)

Answer (score 0):

This is for MySQL

```
 SELECT MAX(WeightedScore),
          MIN(WeightedScore) 
   FROM table
   GROUP BY CompanyName;
```

For SQL Server refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1299598/4576237

Answer (score 0):

Your initial query used the order by DESC to bring the highest first .. just reverse that:
Leave it ASC and the order will be reversed .. again pick the =1 item ..

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by companyname order by weightedscore ASC ) ...
```