# How do you get the rows that contain the max value for each grouped set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

table name :-   my_test

```
compid  roundno
1        1
2        1
2        2
```

I need output like below

```
compid  roundno
1        1
2        2
```

Comment: `Select compid , MAX(RoundNo) FROM TableName group by compid`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Group by & Max](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299556/sql-group-by-max)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical method is to use `row_number()`:

```
select compid, roundno
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by compid order by roundno desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Notes:

- Use `rank()` if you want all rows with equal values.
- Your simple example could just use `group by` and `max()`.  The above works if there are additional columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `max()` aggregate function `group by` the `compid` column

```
select compid, max(roundno)
from tbl
group by compid;
```

Answer (score 2):

use aggregate function. - Max()

```
select compid,max(roundno)
from my_test
group by compid
```